Spring hibernate is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
I am upgrading our project to wildfly 30 with latest spring, hibernate-core with java 17. While deploying the server, I am facing this issue java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException. I dont have any javax related thing in my project .
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException [in thread "ServerService Thread Pool -- 86"]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562) ~[jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:3.5.0.Final]
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530) ~[jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:3.5.0.Final]
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516) ~[jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:3.5.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhCacheMessageLogger.(EhCacheMessageLogger.java:31) ~[hibernate-ehcache-6.0.0.Alpha7.jar:6.0.0.Alpha7]
at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory.(EhcacheRegionFactory.java:46) ~[hibernate-ehcache-6.0.0.Alpha7.jar:6.0.0.Alpha7]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645) ~[?:?]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.create(StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.create(StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.resolveRegionFactory(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:860) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:960) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractA
Could someone please help me to reslove this issue?
Regards,
Poornima

"I dont have any javax related thing in my project". I am afraid that's not enough of an investigation. You may have libraries that are not compatible with JakartaEE yet. A quick look at the stacktrace points to "hibernate-ehcache". Which is using "6.0.0.Alpha7". That's using EhCache 2 which is not compatible with Jakarta. Please review your build config, especially dependencies where you specify the version yourself. That should be a hint that Spring Boot don't manage them and need more attention.

You have a dependency conflict. Find the library with the updated code and update or disable it
